# How do I activate my usb modem in my VM ubuntu server with windows host?

Tags: server, virtualbox, usb-modem

I have ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64 running in my virtual-box and I want to use gammu to send sms with my HUAWEI E153 HSDPA usb stick. I tried to add the modem in the serial port to see the modem in COM4 or any other COM# but I can't see the modem after configuring the serial ports in the virtual-box configuration.

this are the configuration that I have made:
I had com3 configured as host pipe but after shuting down VB it showed as disconected, same for com4

[image: serial_com3]

I don't know if I should use host pipe or host device.

[image: serial_com4]

lsusb command does not show my modem connected

[image: lsusb command]

HUAWEI 153 Modem

[image: HUAWEI 153 Modem]

Comment: I guess that if you configure a serial port through VirtualBox you would not see a USB device in Ubuntu. Rather, you would see a serial interface. Either set up a USB device in VirtualBox or look for a serial device in `/dev`. BTW this question is more about configuring VirtualBox under Windows than it is about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

These modems require the firmware to be loaded by the driver to initalise the modem, this requires usb level access by the OS.  The serial/comport side of it is just for operational usage after the device is initialised and it wont be visible until that has happened.

You should pass through the whole device as a usb device and not as a serial device or comport. Serial pass through is only really for old school hardware serial ports not usb emulated serial ports.

Another approach would be to configure the modem on the host and then use virtualbox internal networking to pass through the network connection by adding a network adapter in bridged or NAT mode and selecting the correct uplink.  As your host is windows you should be able to use a supported driver on that platform. I wasn't sure if you wanted this modem to be private to the guest or was just struggling to share the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly did you try to activate a serial port for a USB device?  A USB device is not connected to a serial port.  Right below the serial ports are the USB ports.  You should go there, find the port where the modem is connected to, and tell virtualbox to use it.

As soon as the device gets rerouted to the vm, it will get disconnected from your host system and it will stay that way until you close the vm.

Comment: I activate the serial port rather than the usb because gammu says modem should be linked through COM# serial port

Comment: Ok.  If you want to use a USB device in a vm though, you have to redirect the USB port to that vm.  Inside the vm you will probably have to install drivers that do the port bridging or something.  You cannot redirect an actual serial port because your device is not physically connected to one.